# Best way to update 200 items on a list

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio, splistitem, splist

Situation in a VS2010/SP2010 site:
List A with main items
List B with subitems, having a lookup column that points to List A ID
There are about 200 subitems for each item

The Page where users edit info regarding a main item (several fields) also allows users to change info regarding any of the 200 subitems (just a value), delete any of them or add new ones (there will be very few deletions or insertions).

When users click a button to save changes, main item is updated. At this moment each of the 200 subitems might also need updating.

So what's best approach?
- Delete the 200 old items by lookup id and re-insert the 200 new having the new values?

```
var query = from SPListItem item in listSubItems.Items
where (item["idLookup"].ToString() == id_Lookup)
    select item;
while (query.Count() > 0)
{
    query.First().Delete();
}

String[,] array_itemID_itemValue = ...;
for (int i = 0, i < 200, i++ )
{
    SPListItem item = listSubItems.AddItem();
    item["idLookup"] = id_Lookup;
    item["idSubItem"] = array_itemID_itemValue[i,0];
    item["valueColumn"] = array_itemID_itemValue[i,1];
    item.Update();
}
```

- Or else, instead of deleting and then re-inserting, do all the necessary updates inside of the `while (query.Count() > 0)` cycle, by searching the `array_itemID_itemValue` for each item on the subItems list, deleting those which are not in the array. Then add the new items from the array.
- Or some other approach/way...
- If 1st approach is best, is there no way to bulk delete?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the below link if you decided to use the bulk delete, well this can still be useful for bulk update

[SPWeb.ProcessBatchData](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/debugging-apps-for-sharepoint-online/)